# How to mock lifecycle hooks with vue-test-utils

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

Method one:

```
const mixin = {
  beforeCreate() {
    // do something
  }
}

mount(TestComponent, {
  mixins: [mixin]
})
```

and method two:

```
const mixin = {
  beforeCreate() {
    // do something
  }
}

localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.mixin(mixin)

mount(TestComponent, {
  localVue
})
```

both methods not work for me. I get an error: 'Cannot read property 'props' of undefined' on development environment and on CodeSandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/4031x2r769

How to correctly mock lifecycle hooks?

Answer (score 1):

Your examples in question are correct but your *CodeSandbox* mixin syntax is incorrect(it should be an object). But main problem is that mixin lifecycle hooks are called **before** component ones, so your `msg` assignment is overwritten by component(see mixin merging [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Option-Merging)).

If you change `created` in mixin to `mounted` for example then it will be passed, because `HelloWorld` does not change `msg` field in that hook(or hook does not exist).

There is my fixed test code from CodeSandbox:

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import { mount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";
import HelloWord from "../src/components/HelloWorld.vue";

describe("test mocks", () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();

  const msg = "from mock";
  let mixin = {
    // change hook to "later" one to  make it work
    mounted() {
      this.msg = msg;
    }
  }

  localVue.mixin(mixin);

  const wrapper = mount(HelloWord, {
    localVue
  });

  it("hook created", () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.msg).eq(msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: I added mounted method to the component and it is not overriden by mixin

Comment: Mixin can not override component lifecycle hook, it just call before component one. I added `mounted` hook to *mixin* in example because mouted invoked later than `created` hook of component.

Comment: Not an answer for this question.